# MySQL was frozen for an hour, and all transaction get processed after that. How come?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

In our environment, we have 2 MySQL (Master & Replica)

Today, we have really strange case.

The data in master sql get frozen for an hour!
By frozen, i mean, there is no new record to, AT LEAST, 1 table (as far as we know)

But it still accessible by read.

This happened in production environment.

All application still can access, insert, update.

But nothing changes in the database itself.

After that frozen window pass, all the queries during that frozen window get executed!

We suspect it's query lock issue.
But i checked mysql.slow_log and can't find any suspect queries.
All queries get executed under a minute.

My question is..

1. Is it deadlock issue? Why does it not log to mysql.slow_log table?
2. How to prevent this? MySQL doesn't have query timeout as default value? How come 1 hour query block everything.
3. Can we specified parameter to log the queries that has high lock time?

Thank you so much.

P.S. I'm using CloudSQL mysql 5.7.11 in

Comment: What were you attempting to do when data got frozen? 
You can increase the performance and possibly avoid slowdowns and freezes of your database by choosing a larger instance with more RAM and CPU. What happens if you increase the value of these parameters?

Comment: In relation to your point 3), if you want to enable logs at a level useful for investigating your issue, you may read the preferred reply to the stack question "Is there a way to enable an SQL log to see/optimize my queries using CloudSQL": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745899/is-there-a-way-to-enable-an-sql-log-to-see-optimize-my-queries-using-cloudsql